# How do I compare two EXE files, find differences and decompile those with Cutter or Radare2?

Tags: disassembly, decompiler, hexdump, radare2, ghidra

After struggling for days, I'd like to ask the community :)

I have two exe files. Both at the same size and pretty big (around 80MB).

- The first exe is the original file, which has been compiled some time ago. I also have the corresponding PDB file.
- The second file is almost identical to the first, but it has been binary patched at several locations.

I managed to decompile the files with Cutter (Radare2 GUI), but thinking about the file-size, it's almost impossible to go through every single method.

With an Hex Editor (Hex Fiend), I managed to get every single offset location, where the patch has been applied. Now I'm trying to find these offsets with Cutter to decompile the locations.

The Question is: How?
When I open the Hexdump in Cutter, it seems that everything is not in place and I might need an offset. Setting an offset at the loading-screen in Cutter seems not to do anything. Am I using it wrong?

Example:

*HexFiend*

```
Offset                Hex Data                                         Text
474942-474956         47 65 74 4D 6F 64 75 6C 65 48 61 6E 64 6C 65 41  GetModuleHandleA
```

*Cutter*

```
Offset                Hex Data                                         Text
0x0060713E-0x0060714D 47 65 74 4D 6F 64 75 6C 65 48 61 6E 64 6C 65 41  GetModuleHandleA
```

474942 is 0x73F3E, but that's far away from 0x0060713E

Maybe I need other tools?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Of course the offsets are different. HexFied is a hex editor that shows the offset in the file. Cutter is a reverse engineering tool that shows the address the code in the process's RAM would have if the executable would be loaded/executed.

Comment: Robert, thank you! I thought, that the HexDump in Cutter also shows the offset in the file, but in this case, you are completely right. I needed to calculate the offsets, which I've done with a combination of "objdump" and "hexdump".